# Formula to send reminder

Tags: formula, formula-field

I want to send remainder to contact owner on the contact birthday date.I want formula to calculate whether the date is falling on weekend so that if it is Saturday I would send 1 prior and Sunday 2 prior notifications

Can I have formula to check whether the date is falling on weekday or weekend

Comment: I want to send email to the contact owner saying that he has birthday remainder if the contact birthday comes on weekdays the email would be sent on the same day else if it falls on Saturday email would be sent one day before. if the birthday falls on Sunday 2 before can i know how to achieve the logic

Comment: Given all your requirements, this is probably easier done in an apex class than in a formula field with a workflow rule.

Comment: I want send a remainder to the contact owner for birthday remainder for the field birthday in the contact object. 
If the birthday falls on week day notification has to be sent on the same else if on Saturday one day before and else if on Sunday two days before

can i know how to achieve the above logic

Answer (score 1):

To find the day of the week from a Date value, use a known Sunday (e.g. January 7, 1900) and subtract it from the date (e.g. TODAY()) to get the difference in days. The MOD() function finds the remainder of this result when divided by 7 to give the numerical value of the day of the week between 0 (Sunday) and 6 (Saturday). The formula below finds the result and then returns the text name of that day.

```
CASE(   MOD( date - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ),   0, "Sunday",   1, "Monday",   2, "Tuesday",   3, "Wednesday",   4, "Thursday",   5, "Friday",    "Saturday" )
```

More date formula help:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/usefulFormulaFields/Content/formula_examples_dates.htm